# Changing Resource encoding from Windows 1252 to UNICODE UTF-8 with signatures

Tags: c++, visual-c++, unicode, encoding, utf-8

I am working on an older project (compiled with UNICODE defined) and came across a problem within the .rc. For example, a static text element which includes “©” defined in a DIALOGEX resource by

```
LTEXT "Copyright ©”,IDC_COPYRIGHT_STATIC,7,154,110,8
```

The resource file, probably created by MSVC application wizard many years ago and migrated forward with each release, now looks like this:

```
#if !defined(AFX_RESOURCE_DLL) || defined(AFX_TARG_ENU)
LANGUAGE LANG_ENGLISH, SUBLANG_ENGLISH_US
#pragma code_page(1252) //present for over 10 years 
#endif
```

For many years the © display correctly but recently appeared as “Å©” or even “½¿”. Obviously, an encoding issue, but I needed to understand how and why before making changes. So, after researching, these three properties in the .rc play a part in the bug and the encoding:

1. The presence or absence of “#pragma code_page(…)” in the .rc
2. The encoding used to **Save with Encoding**… the .rc file
3. **Save with Encoding**… .rc “with signature” or “without signature” (meaning BOM?)

[image: Save with Encoding...]

As an empirical test, changing these things in the .rc and looking at the result text in dialogue

| #pragma code_page(…) | Save with Encoding | Signature(BOM) | Text in Dlg |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| code_page(1252) | Original file | n/a | Å© |
| code_page(1252) | Windows 1252 | n/a | © |
| code_page(1252) | UTF-8 65001 | BOM | Å© |
| code_page(1252) | UTF-8 65001 | No BOM | Å© |
| code_page(65001) | Windows 1252 | n/a | © |
| code_page(65001) | UTF-8 65001 | BOM | © |
| code_page(65001) | UTF-8 65001 | No BOM | © |
| No code_page in .rc | UTF-8 65001 | BOM | © |
| No code_page in .rc | UTF-8 65001 | No BOM | Å© |

I can explicitly **Save with Encoding** all .rc files encoding as Windows (1252) OR encoding as UNICODE UTF-8 with signatures (and delete the #pragma code_pages). The specific bug will go away, but is this the best solution?

It seems switching from Windows 1252 to UNICODE UTF-8 is a step forward and the right way to go long term. Is there any problem with this? Or better solutions?

Comment: Whether you save the `.rc` source as Windows-1252 or as UTF-8 doesn't really matter, as long as you compile the file using the correct encoding. Resource strings are always stored in the final executable as UTF-16, so the resource compiler will have to convert your strings from Win-1252/UTF-8 to UTF-16 one way or the other. Mismatch the encoding and you will get bad results.

Comment: Met the same issue. `#pragma code_page(1252)` had no effect on French and German text. I chose UTF-16 LE for the .rc file and it worked!

Comment: @MaxVlasov I believe the resource compiler is fine with UTF-16LE (so long as the file has a BOM), so saving the .rc file as UTF-16 is already better than *some* ANSI encoding. Still, a very popular SCM (Git) straight-up fails to interpret text files stored as UTF-16. Storing as UTF-8 makes sense, even when it is slightly more expensive to compile.

Answer (score 1):

Raymond Chen explains the encoding issues in the resource compiler in a [blog post](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569) stating that when using UTF-8 as encoding for rc files you should not use a BOM/Signature and include a `#pragma code_page(65001)`.

According to a [Developer Community issue](https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/t/visualstudio-v1590-resource-editor-using-utf-8-bom/384705) there are problems in the resource compiler prior to version v10.0.19505.1001. This fixed version ships with Windows SDK 10.0.20348.0