# MFC, my resource file *.rc corrupted after any change I do

Tags: c++, mfc, dialog, resource-files, rc

I have a MFC dialog-based application. whenever I change anything in the resource file *my_project_name*.rc file, all the dialogs' captions got corrupted like the image below:

[image: how captions look after any change]

The change I did was changing order of two edit controls in a dialog to change the order of focus goes when pressing Tab button. Got the idea from [this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4163156/change-tab-order-by-code-in-a-mfc-dialog/30777486#30777486).

I moved the two edit controls from the last of my dialog controls area in the resource file to the middle.

### Edit 01

I modified the resource file using VSCode, I open it as a text file, do my changes and save it.

Even after I undo the changes no fix for this.

I have a backup for my resource file. when I replace it with the corrupted one everything goes normal.

But I still don't know why and how to avoid or fix the problem I'm in.

Any other idea to change the order of focus on elements when Tab pressed?

Comment: You don't say how you are editing the resource file, I'll presume you are using a text editor of some kind? All the ????? that appear in your dialog would indicate that you've inadvertently converted the text encoding, so the original encoding is no longer valid. Using Notepad++ pay attention to the Encoding type before and after.

Comment: *thanks for God I have a backup for my resource file*  Why aren't you using a source control system, like **git** or **source depot**?

Comment: This is a mismatch between delcared (or implied) character encoding and actual character encoding. You (or your text editor) probably saved the file as UTF-8, but there's a `#pragma code_page()` directive that claims some other encoding. One solution is to save the .rc file as UTF-8 and put `#pragma code_page(65001)` at the top (removing all other `code_page` directives). See [The Resource Compiler defaults to CP_ACP, even in the face of subtle hints that the file is UTF-8](https://devblogs.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20190607-00/?p=102569) for more complete information.

Comment: @user20716902 you suggest do the edits using Notepad++ ?

Comment: @IbrahimTEslim Notepad++ is the best text editor for Windows, but whatever editor you use the important part is to **pay attention to the text encoding** and don't change it when you do your edit.

Comment: @Eljay I have a copy of the whole project.

Comment: @IbrahimTEslim *when I replace it with the corrupted one everything goes normal.* -- You should have compared the normal one with the corrupted one so that you can see what the differences are, thus get a better idea of what happened.

Comment: @john Thanks a lot body. I applied the same changes using Notepad++ and yes the encoding was different, seems the VSCode automatically change the encoding to UTF-8 while at first originally it was in ANSI encoding, the problem solved thx.

Comment: A *source control system* ought to be used for the **whole** project.  So, yes, you'd have a copy of the whole project.

Comment: To provide a definitive answer, please update the question with the following information: `1` What are the first 3 bytes of the "corrupted" .rc file (open the file in a hex editor to find out). `2` Does the .rc file contain any `#pragma code_page()` directives? `3` Do character strings in the "corrupted" .rc file appear as intended in a text editor?

Comment: Related: [Changing Resource encoding from Windows 1252 to UNICODE UTF-8 with signatures](https://stackoverflow.com/q/71281527/1889329).

Answer (score -1):

Thanks to commenters, it was encoding problem, because I was applying the changes using VSCode, and VSCode change the original encoding (ANSI) to UTF-8 so this was what causing the problem.

The solution was applying edits using Notepad++. that solved the problem.

Comment: Well, I wouldn't say that "VS Code changed ..." but rather that "you saved (albeit inadvertently) with the wrong encoded. In Visual Studio it is automatic and will flag to save with UTF encoding if the content has the extra characters. At-least, it does that for source files. Glad you are sorted.